# Java: how to implement private abstract methods?

Tags: java

Is it possible to define a private abstract class in Java? How would a Java developer write a construct like below?

```
public abstract class MyCommand {
    public void execute()
    {
        if (areRequirementsFulfilled())
        {
            executeInternal();
        }
    }
    private abstract void executeInternal();
    private abstract boolean areRequirementsFulfilled();
}
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can't have `private abstract` methods in Java.

When a method is `private`, the sub classes can't access it, hence they can't override it.

If you want a similar behavior you'll need `protected abstract` method.

> It is a compile-time error if a method declaration that contains the keyword `abstract` also contains any one of the keywords `private`, `static`, `final`, `native`, `strictfp`, or `synchronized`.

And

> It would be impossible for a subclass to implement a `private abstract` method, because `private` methods are not inherited by subclasses; therefore such a method could never be used.

---

**Resources :**

- [JLS - 8.4.3. Method Modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3)
- [JLS - 8.4.3.1. `abstract` Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.1)

Comment: Actually, private methods *can* be accessed by subclasses - as long as those subclasses are enclosed by the super class.

Comment: @gustafc, even so, if your class is enclosed in the super class you have two choices, either this class is static, then the abstract method isn't accessible (not from a static environment), or the class isn't static but to have one instance of the subclass you need an instance from the super class which isn't instantiable (because it's abstract) nor extendable from outside.

Comment: @ColinHebert: not quite true, as a (hypothetically private) abstract method could also be overridden in a static inner class (not only in a non-static inner class), so it could have made sense to allow private abstract methods in the same spirit as private constructors are allowed (which also only can be invoked from inner classes).

Answer (score 8):

That would be `protected` instead of `private`. It means that only classes that extend `MyCommand` have access to the two methods. (So do all classes from the same package, but that's a minor point.)