# Abstract classes and private methods

Tags: java, oop

A theoretical question about "Object oriented programming" in general, and in java specifically.
So say I have a "SpaceShip" class which is abstract, and would like to extend it and create another class which is "SpaceShipTypeX" and "SpaceShipTypeZ"
maybe more in the future, but anyhow both should have some same code/methods like say, "fire()", "speedUp()" etc...
I can implement these in the abstract class so I can reuse the code (Great!)
and/or change it for each SpaceShip.
now The problem occurs when I want to implement a method which is "getHit()" - which reduced the SpaceShip's health when it gets a hit.
**But I want it to be implemented in each of the classes in a different manner also I want it to be private in them, but they all have the same method signature so it must be In the abstract class for polymorphism reasons**, though I want it to be private because I want to hide it from the api, because its and internal function and doesn't want other users to be bothered with it.
So because I cannot use private functions in the abstract class I'm stuck.
what should I do? ***(Also I want to avoid using protected because It will be shown in the java docs and is sort of a "public api" because some user can work in the same package and accidentally use it")***

some code for fun:

```
public abstract class SpaceShip {
    public health = 100;

    public abstract void fire();
    public abstract void speedUp();
    private abstract void getHit(); // <------ It's not allowed (and doesn't make sense but I need it)

}
```

spaceshipY:

```
public class SpaceShipX extends SpaceShip{
    public void fire(){
    // TODO: implement
    }

    public void speedUp() {
    // TODO: implement
    }
}
```

THE METHOD I WOULD LIKE TO HIDE FROM THE public API:

```
private void getHit() {
// TODO: reduce some health (IMPLEMENT)
}
```

Comment: Please show code demonstrating what you are trying to do. It is hard to follow a description in words.

Comment: "I can implement these in the abstract class so I can reuse the code (Great!)" Inheritance is not the only tool for code reuse: composition is an (often better) alternative.

Comment: *I cannot use private functions in the abstract class*: yes, you can. And a method can be protected, too.

Comment: Well, what about `protected`?

Comment: Ok, I edited the question I got confused I meant that the function be in all the subclasses of the abstract one, and I want to to be private still, (please check the bold lines)

Comment: This answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851747/java-how-to-implement-private-abstract-methods

Comment: @yali nope, please read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Definig something in the superclass as a means of reusability. I am not sure to what extent that would be a good practice.

Are you sure the algorithm of getting Hit would be aways the same ?

What if one ship can get explosive damage, the other ship get electric damage , and the third ship get hit by EMP. Would the damage aways be the same ?

With respect to the question, Yes you can use private method in abstract class, but I would recommend you to read **Composition over inheritance** before making your choice:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

UPDATE:

You should can think in this direction:

- Ship has 1 or more Vulnerabilities
- Vulnerability has type - Fire, Explosive,EMP ..... You can think of it as a function over the Damage.
- Ship can produce Damage.
- Damage can have one or more types.

This is a producer consumer way of thinking that involves mroe composition than actual inheritance.

Comment: No, the algorithm of getting hit won't be always the same that's why I want it to be implemented in the subclasses but I want to hide it from the users and I want each class to guarantee to have this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is exactly about *protected* modifier usage.
Of course, you can use private modifiers in abstract classes.
But only if you 200% sure that logic that implemented inside will not be changed in descendants - otherwise it will be a real pain to support.
The second issue that if you implicitly call these private methods implicitly in descendants via superclass - it becomes hard to remember and understand what's really going on (especially if you will have a 3-4-more level of inheritance)

Comment: I want to avoid using protected because It will be shown in the java docs and is sort of a "public api" because some user can work in the same package and accidentally use it

Comment: Consider use interfaces in this case.
Something like :

public interface Vulnerable {
   void getHit();
}

public class  SpaceShipX extends SpaceShip impements Vulnerable { .. }

Comment: Sorry interface is not an option, a SpaceShipX is a SpaceShip...

Answer (score 0):

You can't accomplish exactly what you are trying to do.  Private methods are not inherited by subclasses.  This is because calls to private methods are statically bound at compile time, so dynamic binding (i.e. polymorphism) cannot take place.

As others have indicated, the closest things available to what you are looking for is either protected, or package private.

Please note that package private methods are only inherited by a subclass [if the subclass is within the same package](https://www.sitepoint.com/interface-and-inheritance-in-java-inheritance/).

Answer (score -1):

There are three or four types of method identifiers. Private, Public, Protected, and/ or Final. Protected Methods allow inheritance access by its subclass but not by any unrelated class.